# GWT Based UI Control library

Tags: gwt

Is there a GWT UI Control library that's based on GWT? (commercial or not)
I would expect that in such a library the grid for example would extend the DataGrid or the CellTable and would add functionality, like grouping,filters,sizing of columns.

Answer (score 1):

Please checkout this library https://vaadin.com/gwt.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT

Try gwt-bootstrap if you want something that has extended gwt widgets. Link is 
http://gwtbootstrap.github.io/

Docs link

http://gwtbootstrap.github.io/gwt-bootstrap/apidocs/

What you want might be this, try

> **http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellTable**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, what I'm looking for is for a library based on standard GWT widgets like CellTAble, all libraries I've seen don't extend any standard GWT Widgets.

Comment: Check edits that I have made to my answer if that might help you